# representation of very large numbers multiplied to pow()

Tags: c++, math, floating-point

In my calculation I have several input variables

> M_s = 1.989 ×〖10〗^30
>       G = 6.67384 ×〖10〗^(-11)
>       a=1.496 ×〖10〗^8

When I write something like

```
long double G = 6.67384 * (pow(10,-11));
```

I get the error message:

```
c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\1.det.earth location in orbit\1.det.earth location in orbit\1.det.earth location in orbit.cpp(15): error C2668: 'pow' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\math.h(583): could be 'long double pow(long double,int)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\math.h(535): or       'float pow(float,int)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\math.h(497): or       'double pow(double,int)'
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(int, int)'
```

How can I express the statement "G is equal to 6.67384 multiplied to 10 to the power of -11" and get the correct answer? What STL library should I include?

Comment: long double G = 6.67384 e-11.

Answer (score 4):

Just change this line

```
long double G = 6.67384 * (pow(10,-11));
```

to this

```
long double G = 6.67384 * pow(10.0, -11);
```

The problem is, that you are passing `int` for the two arguments of `pow` the compiler expects one of three

```
long double pow(long double, int);
float pow(float, int);
double pow(double, int);
```

so it is confused about which function to call.

But since in C++ you can express powers of 10 directly like this

```
long double G = 6.67384E-11;
```

you don't really need the `pow` function.

Comment: yes sure. so, that G variable once multiplied to pow actually gives the the processor an idea which construction of pow to use ? since it was declared long double type for G and then we multiply it to pow (thus pow is expected to take arguments of (long double, long double)). Am I right ?

Comment: The first argument is `double`, actually. `10.0f` is a float literal.

Comment: @MuradEminov No, the compiler does not detemrmine which function to call from the return value, but since you passed an integer, it could be promoted to `float` or `double` or `long double` and since you didn't specify one, the compiler was confused. With my solution the first argument will be `double` so it's not confused anymore, the overloaded function that will be called is `double pow(double, int)` and the return value will be promoted to `long double`

Answer (score 3):

Benjamin Bannier had the better idea in the comments. But that had a space which isn't allowed; cleaned up it looks like this:

```
long double G = 6.67384e-11;
```

This can be more accurate, and probably is faster, because the conversion to binary is done by the compiler. Of course, an a scientist the value is familiar, and I realize that the real accuracy problem is caused by our limited measurements of G. You really don't need `long double`, a `float` would be sufficient today and a `double` will be sufficient for the foreseeable future (we're not going to know G to 15 digits any time soon)

Answer (score 1):

You need to read and understand the error message:

```
'pow' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
could be 'long double pow(long double,int)'
or       'float pow(float,int)'
or       'double pow(double,int)'
          while trying to match the argument list '(int, int)'
```

The message says that the compiler was not able to guess what overload of the function you wanted because the first argument is an `int` and it can be cast in three different ways.

If you need a `long double` result, then pass a `long double` constant or cast it:

```
10.l
(long double)10
```